# Can I change the Windows "I don't know the resolution" resolution?

Tags: windows, resolution

When Windows doesn't know the resolution of the monitor, it decides to play it safe and assume 800x600, and resizes my windows to fit in that size.  Then once the monitor resolution becomes known, the windows are still at their reduced size.  This happens sometimes just for a moment, but all my windows have resized.

I understand I can't stop Windows from resizing the windows, but can I change its idea of the "safe size" to use when the size is unknown?

Comment: Almost definitively not, but I have no evidence for that.